# In FAT file systems, why does the data area start at cluster 2?

Tags: filesystems

For FAT file systems, to perform a cluster to sector calculation it is well documented that...

```
StartOfDataArea + ((ClusterNum - 2) * SectorsPerCluster)
```

...will calculate the first sector in the cluster.

Why is the value 2 subtracted from the cluster number?  Most explanations say it is because the data area actually starts at cluster 2, but why?  What \ where are the two clusters that are accounted for in the calculation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first two sectors hold special data so are omitted from the calculations.

You may find the information in Wikipedia
[Design of the FAT file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system),
section
[File Allocation Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system#File_Allocation_Table):

> The first two entries in a FAT store special values:
>
> The first entry (cluster 0 in the FAT) holds the FAT ID [...text deleted...]
>
> The second entry (cluster 1 in the FAT) nominally stores the
>   end-of-cluster-chain marker as used by the formater, but typically
>   always holds 0xFFF / 0xFFFF / 0x0FFFFFFF, that is, with the exception
>   of bits 31-28 on FAT32 volumes these bits are normally always set.

Comment: Thanks for your response--this makes sense.  To clarify, the first two entries in the FAT point to clusters (not sectors as indicated) the size of which is defined by the system's sectors per cluster value.  This explains why the offset is ClusterNum-2 resulting in a much larger offset rather than just removing two sectors from the total.